# Make a span rotate on click using CSS transform property in JQuery .animate() plugin

Tags: jquery, html, animation, rotation

I have a Menu trigger with a arrow down to the right of it .When i click the trigger the menu shows but i want the arrow to rotate at 180deg.I tried that with jQuery animation but didnt work.Here is my [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/phqh9emg/1/)

```
$('#slide-trigger').on('click', function () {
    $('#slide-nav > ul').slideToggle(400, function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('showing');
    });
    $('#slide-trigger > span').animate({ 'transform' : 'rotateY(180deg)' });
});
```

Comment: Do you want it to rotate or simply flip? Cause my understanding of rotate would be an animation of it rotating. I ask cause I say that the selected answer, the arrow isn't exactly rotating as much as inverting orientation. Clarification isn't necessary, just curious.

Comment: Yes you are right, I want it rotating but i didnt knew how to make that . Can you help me ?

Comment: Yes of course, but how do you want it to rotate? So say, it is facing down (default - closed menu) - you click, and the arrow will then be pointing upwards. Do you want it to rotate upwards to the right or to the left? Should it be a quick rotation? etc. Just provide me with some details as to how you imagine it functioning.

Comment: Thank you very much ! I would like it to rotate upwards in a quick rotation , i think that would look good .

Comment: Okay, I must not have been clear - I am going to make the example rotate upwards, quickly, but away from the text (i.e. rotate up to the right) - Give me a minute, I'm jumping between questions.

Comment: Ok , sorry if I didnt provided enough details . Thank you again !

Comment: I don't know why people ask for something and accepts something else. If you get an answer and some one else just modify. You must upvote it but accepting it....? Actual Answer deserves accept for an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, basic animates can't animate non-numeric CSS properties. So i would suggest you giving `.toggleClass` JQuery Plugin so that it would be easy to use.

**UPDATE :** Here the **numeric value** i.e. `180`for degree is causing the issue.

```js
    $('#slide-trigger').on('click', function () {
        $('#slide-nav > ul').slideToggle(400, function () {
            $(this).toggleClass('showing');
        });
        $('#slide-trigger > span').toggleClass('transform-class');
    });
```

```css
#slide-nav {
    position: fixed;
    display: inline-block;
    top: 100px;
    left: 0;
}

#slide-nav ul{
    padding:0;
    display:none;
}

#slide-nav ul li {
    position:relative;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 7px 20px;
}

#slide-nav ul li a {
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

#slide-nav ul .active a {
    color: rgba(0,0,0,.75);
}

#slide-nav ul .active:before{
        content: "";
        width: 15px;
        height: 1.5px;
        background-color: black;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 0;
}


#slide-trigger {
    font-size: 1.4em;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 20px 0;
}
#slide-trigger span {
    font-size: 0.8em;
}

.transform-class
{
    display:inline-block;
    transform:rotateX(180deg) !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav id="slide-nav">
                <div id="slide-trigger">Click here <span>&#9660</span></div>
                <ul>
                    <li  class="active"><a href="#">Link1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link4</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
```

[DEMO : FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/phqh9emg/5/).

Comment: Thank you , that worked perfectly , I also added a transition rule to the span for the effect :D

Comment: Ok great, ya it would work for the transition effect. Anyways glad that it helped you. :)

Answer (score 1):

Okay, building off the answer provided by divy3993 - I used his Fiddle but added the following:

```
.transf {
    -webkit-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
    transition: .5s ease-in-out;
    display:inline-block;
    transform:rotateX(180deg);
}
```

So as you can see, I added the "transition" property and removed the "!important" tag.

Now I know I said the rotation would go 1. Start facing down 2. Quickly rotate to the right 90 degrees 3. Finish by rotating a full 180 degrees, ending up facing up. However, that would require a different solution.

If you are happy with the solution I provided, great, if not let me know and I can create a "keyframe" animation that will give you the smooth rotation that I just described. As you will notice, my current solution will animate sort of a "flip" rotate.

** **UPDATE** ** I forgot to include my Fiddle link - https://jsfiddle.net/rockmandew/6j3xaq2d/1/

Let me know if this works as a solution for you.

------- Second Update --------

Keyframes are pretty simple - this is an example of a fairly simple Keyframe:

```
@-webkit-keyframes rotate-rt {
  0% {    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
  50% {   -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg); }
  100% {   -webkit-transform: rotate(-180deg); }
}
```

You can see that I set percentages, these represent the percent complete. So at 50% it will be rotated to the -90deg point and by the time it finishes it will rotate -180 degrees from its initial point. The more step you put in the animation, the smoother it will be. You will also need to toggleClasses for this to work since you are going to animate it up, you will want to animate it down. To do this, you simply add this do your function:

```
$('#slide-trigger > span').toggleClass('initial transf');
```

As you can see, I added "initial" to the function, I also had to add "initial" as a class to the span element. Onclick, these classes will toggle each other.

To initiate the keyframes/animation, you need to apply the following to the class you want animated. Since ".tranf" is the class that is applied when the menu is opened, you will want to apply this to that class:

```
-webkit-animation-name: rotate-rt;
-webkit-animation-duration: .5s;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
```

Notice the animation name is whatever I named my Keyframes. Here is some good supporting documentation on the issue: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/keyframe-animation-syntax/

Comment: I like it but that works slightly the same as the answer above . As I understood do I need to use keyframes to make it rotate like u described above ? You don't need to make the code for me but if u can just give me some tips because i never used keyframes before .

Comment: Ahhh sorry, I didn't see the transition effect in his fiddle, thought I was providing an additional layer. As far as your question goes, yes you will need to use keyframes to achieve this. Let me gather some information for you, that I think will help.

Comment: I'm going to update my answer with more information about keyframes - note that I have messed around with the fiddle I provided - I am going to comment out any changes I made after posting my answer, that way you can uncomment things and play around with them as you feel necessary.

Comment: No problem, i took a look at the code from the updated JSFIDDLE and i got a small idea of how keyframes work :D . EDIT : Thank you for all your help , i got an idea of how it works now !

Comment: I have commented out my updates, so you can play around with it. I have submitted my updated answer and I have provided you with some additional documentation that I hope you find helpful.

Comment: Yes , it was very helpful ! Thank you so much !